# SQL query construction for finding rows from multiple values in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: `jobs` and `applications`.

`jobs` has columns including `id` (the key) and `user_id` (the ID of the user who created the row).

`applications` has columns including `job_id` (the ID of the job which the application correlates to).

The query I'm trying to construct will perform the following:

1. Search for all rows in the `jobs` table that has a specific `user_id`
2. Search for all rows in the `applications` table whose `job_id` correlates to the `id`s returned in the previous search

e.g.

**`jobs` table**

```
id    user_id    ...>
1     1          ...
2     3          ...
3     1          ...
```

**`applications` table**

```
id    job_id     ...>
1     3          ...
2     1          ...
3     2          ...
```

If I run the query where `user_id`=1, it should return rows 1 and 2 from the `applications` table as they correlate to the jobs where `user_id`=1.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Using join you can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  select app.* from applications app, jobs j
  where j.id = app.job_id
  and j.user_id = '1'
```

Using join.

Comment: This returns the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where j.user_id = '1'`

Comment: Ops, sorry. Edited now.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this - I will use this to learn about the `join` function. So useful.

Comment: You should do that! joins is the first thing you should learn about relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can just join these two tables to make one "bigger table" with all of your data. You will join them on common column, in your case its Id = job_id.

The query will look like this :

```
select a.* 
from applications a 
join jobs j on a.job_id = j.id  
where j.user_id = '1'
```